# What type of rivet is this?

Tags: fasteners, rivets

This is a pivot point on a linkage in my coffee table. It appears to be a rivet with a tail that was pressed with a cross-shaped punch to widen it. I haven't see something like this before. Is there a name for this? What is the benefit of cross-punching it?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was hit with a cross-shaped punch to get that side or head to expand.

Usually done with a single blow for speed and low cost. Other choices can be nuts and bolts with nylock nuts so they don’t come loose easily.

Comment: also called staking